# spring boot not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-web

I am new to spring boot.

I have a sample of it.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0.M4</version>
    </parent>
    <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- Package as an executable JAR -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Allow access to Spring milestones and snapshots -->
    <!-- (you don't need this if you are using anything after 0.5.0.M2) -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

java class:

package bootSample;

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

when i run it, the below exception is raised

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'compression[min-response-size]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'compression[min-response-size]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'compression[min-response-size]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties]: Bean property 'compression[min-response-size]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:514)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:697)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at bootSample.SampleController.main(SampleController.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'compression[min-response-size]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'compression[min-response-size]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'compression[min-response-size]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties]: Bean property 'compression[min-response-size]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getCustomizers(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1499)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'compression[min-response-size]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'compression[min-response-size]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'compression[min-response-size]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties]: Bean property 'compression[min-response-size]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:915)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:730)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:626)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:78)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:611)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:232)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:311)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'compression[min-response-size]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties]: Bean property 'compression[min-response-size]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:718)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:936)
    ... 42 more
```

properties file:

```
 server.compression.enabled: true
 server.compression.min-response-size: 1
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: i add complete error log now

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with your property file. can you add it please

Comment: You're using some very old version of spring boot. It's even some milestone. You should update to some full stable version. You can use http://start.spring.io/ or Spring tool suite.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which i see might be the problem

1.The version of springboot you are using its very old, the current version is 1.3 and there is no need of any milestones to that

2.The properties for the server you are using might have some problem , try removing it or post ur full properties file such that we can help .